# How to draw a line once I drag on screen in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Actually I want to draw a line once I drag on screen.

**Please see the image:**

[image]

Suppose I swipe from point **A** to point **B**. Then here will be create a line (Like the image).

Please give me an idea how to do it.

Comment: i use image line enstead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easily done by using PanResponer (https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder) and SVG (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg).

**Here is the code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Svg, {Line} from 'react-native-svg';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Platform,
    Text,
    PanResponder,
    Image,
    Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
var height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        //initialize state
        this.panResponder;
        this.state = {
            startTouchX: 0,
            startTouchY: 0,

            endTouchX: 0,
            endTouchY: 0,
        };

        //panResponder initialization
        this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gestureState) => true,
            onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (event, gestureState) => {
                this.setState({
                    startTouchX: event.nativeEvent.locationX.toFixed(2),
                    startTouchY: event.nativeEvent.locationY.toFixed(2),
                });
            },
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gestureState) => false,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (event, gestureState) => false,
            onPanResponderGrant: (event, gestureState) => false,
            onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {},
            onPanResponderRelease: (event, gestureState) => {
                this.setState({
                    endTouchX: event.nativeEvent.locationX.toFixed(2),
                    endTouchY: event.nativeEvent.locationY.toFixed(2),
                });
            },
        });
        this.setState({
            startTouchX: 0,
            startTouchY: 0,

            endTouchX: 0,
            endTouchY: 0,
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
                <View style={styles.childView}>
                    <Svg height={height} width={width} position="absolute">
                        <Line
                            x1={this.state.startTouchX}
                            y1={this.state.startTouchY}
                            x2={this.state.endTouchX}
                            y2={this.state.endTouchY}
                            stroke="red"
                            strokeWidth="8"
                        />
                    </Svg>
                    <View
                        style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    MainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    },

    childView: {
        flex: 1,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    point: {
        height: 22,
        width: 22,
        marginTop: 5,
        position: 'absolute',
        borderRadius: 14,
        backgroundColor: '#afeeee',
    },
});
```

Comment: Hi. This helped me alot.
Can you please tell me if i want to draw more than one line on the screen. How can i do that?

Comment: @HashirSaeed Hi. Extremely sorry, currently I am not working on react native.